# Arrows in tikz-cd are not symmetrical

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

So I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} 

\tikzset{negated/.style = {
        decoration={markings, 
            mark = at position 0.5 with {
                \node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$\backslash$};
            }
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    } 
}

\begin{figure} 
\centering 
\begin{tikzcd} {} & \quad LY\text{-chaos} \\ 
AY\text{-chaos} \arrow[Rightarrow, shift left = 0.5ex]{r} \arrow[Rightarrow, shift left = 0.6ex]{dr} \arrow[Leftarrow, shift left = -1.2ex, negated]{dr} \arrow[Leftarrow, shift left = 1.2ex, negated]{ur} \arrow[Rightarrow, shift left = -0.6ex]{ur} & D\text{-chaos} \arrow[Rightarrow, shift left = 0.7ex]{l} \\ 
{} & T\text{-chaos} 
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the problem is the arrows from/to AY-chaos to/from LY-chaos and T-chaos don't start at the same point (on the x axis).

Comment: Please include youre preamble in the example.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small **compilable** document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that Ti*k*Z tries to be smart and distribute the arrows around the nodes.

You can outsmart it by making the nodes taller, so that the arrows will be anchored on the side of the nodes only. To make the nodes taller, use the `minimum height` key.

The bigger problem, however, is that there are two arrows for each node, so you have to do a bit of manual labour to make it look right.

I also made the nodes the same width with `minimum width` to keep the uniformity.

Finally, I added a small kerning before the hyphen in `AY-chaos`, `LY-chaos`, and `T-chaos` to make seem like one thing.

One thing for you to think about: There is no way to make the arrows start at the same X coordinate without making them too far away, as they are at the east side of node `AY-chaos`, or without making them too cramped. One think that would make it look better is if you somehow made node `AY-chaos` (an even the others) visually taller, maybe drawing the boxes or adding a left bracked... Just a thought :)

Anyway, here it is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\tikzset{negated/.style = {
        decoration={markings, 
            mark = at position 0.5 with {
                \node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$\backslash$};
            }
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    } 
}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={minimum height=1.0cm,minimum width=1.7cm}},column sep=4em,row sep=0pt]
& LY\kern-0.5ex\text{-chaos} \\
  AY\kern-0.5ex\text{-chaos}
  \arrow[Leftarrow , start anchor=north east,
                       end anchor={[yshift= 0.2cm]}, negated]{ur}
  \arrow[Rightarrow, start anchor={[yshift= 0.5ex]},
                       end anchor={[yshift= 0.2cm]south west}]{ur}
  \arrow[Rightarrow, yshift=-0.7ex]{r}
  \arrow[Leftarrow , yshift= 0.7ex]{r}
  \arrow[Rightarrow, start anchor={[yshift=-0.5ex]},
                       end anchor={[yshift=-0.2cm]north west}]{dr}
  \arrow[Leftarrow , start anchor=south east,
                       end anchor={[yshift=-0.2cm]}, negated]{dr}
& D\text{-chaos} \\
& T\kern-0.5ex\text{-chaos}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```